# Is it ok to use Code Sample function in editor just for highlight?

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

Nowadays I see lots of questions using code sample display for highlight, not really on code samples.

`This` is an `example` how it `looks`.

I see comments about they are ok to use, and some other comments saying reverse. Is it ok to use them like that?

Comment: Where in the world are you seeing comments that say this is OK?

Comment: I was thinking this was not ok and wrote so, but someone commented the reverse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375302/why-i-cant-write-mailto-in-datanavigateurlfields?noredirect=1#comment26982571_18375302

Comment: @Kuzgun, the link in your previous comment is a counter-example: Every code block in that question is used to highlight either literal strings or class names. That's all right.

Comment: Even more, @Kuzgun, in that example the OP is adding semantical information ("this is code", which *happens* to be rendered differently when looking at the regular website) rather than formatting ("I want this to look different"). Your suggesting to use bold would be formatting indeed, which would annoy me.

Comment: Oh ok then, thank you  Frédéric Hamidi, Arjan, Mat.

Answer (score 5):

#### No!

Please don't use code formats for things that are not code. The highlight *parts* of a sentence you can use *italics* or **bold**. (Use them sparingly though.)

Plain English words, proper names, trademarks, etc. should not be set in code blocks.

*Do* use inline code blocks for short code snippets (`int answer = 42;`), or for instance to refer to variable names (like `answer` from the previous snippet or code block). Class, interface or type names, functions, etc. are fine in code blocks too (e.g. `NSImmutableCactus` should be set as code).

But if you find that you're following these rules but end up with text that's half English and half code, you would probably be better of refactoring it: explain the issue in plain English, and use a proper code snippet.

Example:

> In `GridView`, I am trying to use `HyperLinkField`,I am trying to write `'mailto:'` into its `DataNavigateUrlFields` parameter, but it renders to nothing: `<a href=''>...</a>`.

This is barely readable. Would be better as something like:

> I'm trying to put an email link in my grid view by setting the URL field to a `mailto` link as follows:
>
> ```
> <foo:GridView BarDegree="full" 
>   DataNavigateUrlFields="<a href=mailto:{0}>{0}</a>" 
>   Orientation="sideways" />
> ```
>
> [Description of what happens]; [Question about how to fix it]

Comment: "italics" is not in *italics* :-/

Comment: Just as an aside: though Stack Exchange does allows for `<i>` and `<b>`, Markdown nicely uses `<em>` and `<strong>` instead. Of course, **often** that *looks* the same.